# jQuery Find <th></th> which are not empty with Certain Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that was working to parse a table to json.

It worked fine like this

```
    <thead id="itemspecthead" class="itemspectheadc">
  <tr>
    <th class="ishead isheadname">Name</th>
    <th class="ishead isheadvalue">Value</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
```

With the script logic:

```
  var headers = [];

  $(rows.shift()).find('th:first:not(:empty), th:nth-child(2):not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
```

But trying to stylize my table, I added a couple other rows to my table header.

```
    <thead id="itemspecthead" class="itemspectheadc">
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="tdheader"><span>Item Specifics:</span></td></tr>
     <tr><td colspan="2" class="speccaption"><span>(Generated from Unique Values from All Listings)</span><br /></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="ishead isheadname">Name</th>
    <th class="ishead isheadvalue">Value</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
```

If I remove the two extra rows in my thead, the script works fine.
It seems the error is in this logic `.find('th:first:not(:empty), th:nth-child(2):not(:empty)')`

I've tried changing it to `.find('th.ishead:first:not(:empty),` and `.find('.ishead th:first:not(:empty),` to find it via classname with no luck.

How can I target my `ishead` th rows while keeping the extra `colspan="2"` rows in my `thead`?

Here's my onclick function that is now returning `name,value,name,value` (duplicating it twice for some reason..).  This is literally my entire on click function script, I removed everything else.

```
$(document).on('click', '#editjson', function() {

  var headers = [];

    $('th.ishead:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  alert('headers: ' + headers);
  console.log(headers);
  });
```

returns `name,value,name,value`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `:not(:empty)` directly to all `th` (not on any particular-one)

Do like below:-

```
$(rows.shift()).find('th.ishead:not(:empty)').each(function () {
  headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
```

***Working sample:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var headers = [];

  $('th.ishead:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
 console.log(headers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead id="itemspecthead" class="itemspectheadc">
  <tr><td colspan="2" class="tdheader"><span>Item Specifics:</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" class="speccaption"><span>(Generated from Unique Values from All Listings)</span><br /></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="ishead isheadname">Name</th>
    <th class="ishead isheadvalue">Value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: @bbruman  table structure need to be correct for code need to work. So check and correct it. As i am sure that my code will work properly if you have correct HTML along with the `ishead` class for `<th>`

Comment: You are correct.  I am so close though.  Any idea on how to get the instance after the first?  -- the second instance.  I've tried `, th:first.ishead.next():not(:empty)` `, th:first.ishead.children().eq(1):not(:empty)`... both are incorrect syntax

Comment: Finally got it.  `th:eq(1).ishead:not(:empty)` or `$('th:first.ishead:not(:empty), th:eq(1).ishead:not(:empty)').each(function ()`...thank you for the help!